# Best way to manage empty field's error

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with a few fields. And I want to display a different error message for each missing field. And if a field is empty I display a jQuery Dialog and the initial form to fill in correctly.

I have done something like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

    if($_POST['email'] && $_POST['email'] != ''){

        if($_POST['password'] &&  $_POST['password']!= ''){

            if($_POST['password'] ==  $_POST['confirm_password'])
            {               
                    ...
                    ...
            }                       

            }else ?>    <div class="dialog" id="dialog" title="Error">  <p>The passwords you entered do not match</p>       </div><?php

        }else ?>    <div class="dialog" id="dialog" title="Error">  <p>Password field is empty</p>      </div><?php

    }else ?>    <div class="dialog" id="dialog" title="Error">  <p>Email field is empty</p>     </div><?php
}else {?>
```

And then I display my form

```
        <form method="post" action="submenu_signup.php">

            <table class="center">

                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" > Email : </td>
                    <td width="50%" > <input class="more_width" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ex : Surgeon5031@example.com"  maxlength="45" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" > Password : </td>
                    <td width="50%" > <input class="more_width" type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="40" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" > Confirm password : </td>
                    <td width="50%" > <input class="more_width" type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" maxlength="40" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" > Service : </td>
                    <td width="50%" > <input class="more_width" type="text" name="service" id="service" placeholder="Ex : Neurosurgery, orthopedics, ..."  maxlength="255" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" > Phone number : </td>
                    <td width="50%" > <input class="more_width" type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" placeholder="Ex : 01234 56 78 90"  maxlength="20" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" > <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Sign up" /> </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        </form>
```

But obviously when the user don't fill correctly, it display the jQuery box but the form no longer exist. And I will not

> CTRL+C CTRL+V

my form after every

> else

I am sure I am not doing it well, but do not know the best practice to do that. I am open to every suggestion (I do not care about replacing jQuery by something else)

Comment: I think because you're nesting the error messages inside `IF` statements, that's causing issues. If you take them outside of each other, and just have them one after the other, it will then process each one regardless of if the previous one is true or false.

Comment: But I don't want to display 10 boxes if the user click on _Submit_ by mistake. That is not very friendly. My goal is to make this page soft and user-friendly. It may be possible that some javascript will help me there to display something when the field is untargeted, any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried jquery validation? http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @Raccoon If the user clicks on Submit, it will process the form. How are you going to determine whether this action is a mistake or not?

Comment: Move `<form>` out of last `else` statement. This will show the form as well as error messages (if there are any). Your form is not showing since after form submission `isset($_POST['submit'])` will be true and the program flow will not go into `else` part of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several answers. What I'd do is to store error messages in an array with the field's name as a key. You can then either display every error message under the field (as in the following example), or choose to display everything in a first big error `<div>`, and then add some error `class` on your field (so that they will be in red for example).

You have an array with each field that has an error, and the message with it, it's quite convenient and you can use it as you want.

```
<?php

    $errorMessages = array();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['email']) {
            $errorMessages['email'] = 'Email field is empty';
        }
        if (empty($_POST['password'] || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']) {
            $errorMessages['password'] = 'The passwords you entered do not match';
        }
        if ( ...other error... ) {
             $errorMessages[{fieldName}] = '{message}';
        }

        if (empty($errorMessages)) {
            // No error : do what you have to do with your datas
        }

?>

<form method="post" action="submenu_signup.php">
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" ><label for="email">Email :</label></td>
            <td width="50%" >
                <input class="more_width" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ex : Surgeon5031@example.com"  maxlength="45" />
                <?php if (!empty($errorMessages['email'])) echo $errorMessages['email']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" ><label for="password">Password :</label></td>
            <td width="50%" >
                <input class="more_width" type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="40" />
                <?php if (!empty($errorMessages['password'])) echo $errorMessages['password']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> ... other fields ... </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

(Note: I'm not sure using HTML `tables` here is a good practice. Use `table` for tables. Use `div` and `p` and other appropriate HTML tags when it's not a `table`.)

You can also use Javascript validation before submitting in PHP. It can be more user-friendly, but you always have to do PHP validation in case the user turned-off Javascript (very easy to play with it if you want to "hack" a form).